# Fade-in element after page load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css-animations

In AngularJS, how can I fade-in the headline in the following example? The idea is to fade-in the headline once it becomes available after page load.

HTML

```
<section class="headline">
    <span class="headlineFade" ng-show="screen.headline">
        {{ screen.headline }}
    </span>
</section>
```

SCSS

```
section.headline
{
    // transition type
    .headlineFade
    {
        -webkit-transition: opacity 3s linear;
        -moz-transition:    opacity 3s linear;
        -o-transition:      opacity 3s linear;
        -ms-transition:     opacity 3s linear;
        transition:         opacity 3s linear;
    }
    // start-value for transition
    .headlineFade.fade-show
    {
        opacity:    0;  // 0 = fully transparent
    }
    // end-value for transition
    .headlineFade.fade-show-active 
    {
        opacity:    1;  // 1 = fully opaque
    }
}
```

Currently, the above css does not seem to do anything. I was hoping it would apply the transition once `screen.headline` is available. But it doesn't. It just shows `screen.headline` without any transition at all.

Comment: Have you considered CSS animations? They play once the element is displayed and you don't need any JS.

Comment: Check the documentation for ng-animate (http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate). With 1.2 this is what you want to use, as it also triggers on ng-show.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add a plunkr?

Did you include `ng-animate`?
Are you using the `.ng-hide` classes? You need to set `display: block !important;` and some small things to get it going.

See [ng-hide documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angHide).